# Swap image src if screen width <= 699

Tags: javascript

I have two images "image-big.jpg" and "image-small.jpg" I want to via javascript detect if screen width <= 699 and change the SRC of my image with class="imageswap" from image-big.jpg to image-small.jpg.

So basically if they are on a portable device it will display the smaller image.

I am novice at best with javascsript and any help is gratefully appreciated!

Comment: This would be easier to achieve using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/), the only caveat being you need to use `background-image` on a `<div>` or something, instead of an `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the window onresize event:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if(window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth===699)
       document.getElementById('myImg').src = 'newSource';
    else if(document.body.offsetWidth && document.body.offsetWidth===669)
       document.getElementById('myImg').src = 'newSource';
};
```

The `else if` is for IE < v.9

Comment: This event is not called at loading, only at resizing.

Comment: Is there a way to call it onload?  My page has an automatic redirect to mobile width if on a mobile device so the script needs to know what the width is cause there is no resizing... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its no in specs but `screen` works fine in all browsers.

```
if(screen.width <= 699){
   // do you logic
}
```

Comment: I am not good with the logic?  Any chance I could get you to help me out???

I have:
<script type="text/javascript">
if(screen.width <= 699){
   document.getElementById('fourthjulImg').src = 'imagepath';
}
</script>

Comment: Yes, it would work but place the `<script></script>` just before the closing `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

1st approach: client-side. Set classname to html tag on dom ready after detection device type. Use css:

```
html.big .image-div {background-image:url('big.jpg')}
html.small .image-div {background-image:url('small.jpg')}
```

2nd approach: redirect. Use 2 different URLs and redirect for small size by detection User-Agent. It's better to use User-Agent (navigator object) than window/screen width

Usually I preffer redirects, because you have better code and page look when you can customize it for specific device. It's the way how leaders behave.

Answer (score 0):

Try media-query.

```
.imageswap{
 background-image:url('small.jpg');
}
    @media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
      background-image:url('small.jpg');
    }
```